# How to return a MySQL select function as a string?

Tags: php, mysql, function

I've been working on my first big website and encountered a problem while trying to create a PHP function that returns a value based on criteria given when the function is called.

I have been having a problem for using the following code, all I could get to return was "DATABASE: 1"

```
function data_r_user($request, $username ) {
    include("login/dbconnect.php");
    $sqli = "SELECT " . $request . " FROM users WHERE username = " . $username;
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconnect,$sqli ) or die();

    return $result;
}
```

After searching up for a while I appear to of tracked the problem to the fact that all SQL queries return an array and not a string (I believe this to be the case sorry if I'm wrong).

I thought returning a single result would be easy but it appears not to be.

So basically I want a way to return a single result from this function and I'm indifferent as to whether it's procedural or object.

Comment: `$return` is not defined and your query is invalid and open to SQL injections. Strings need to be quoted. Once you get the query working use fetch `$result` and set it to `$return`. Also `or die()` is kind of useless, output something there so you know why it died, or use the error reporting function so you get information.

Comment: Read the manual about $result type of mysqli_query() - http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php

Comment: yeah the return was a fault on my end because i removed some items so it was focusing on where the issue was.   fixed it now.

Comment: `$sqli` is still an invalid query so you will result in the `die`. See the rest of the comment.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using prepared statements is highly recommended, so forgive me for not pointing you to [mysqli_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) but instead showing you how to do this securely:

```
function data_r_user($request, $username ) {
    // you want require and only do it once
    require_once("login/dbconnect.php");

    $return = '';

    // white list the allowed columns
    $columns_allowed = array('id', 'username', 'firstname', 'lastname');
    if (! in_array($request, $columns_allowed)) {
        // if they ask for something not allowed give them nothing
        return '';

    }

    /* create a prepared statement */
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbconnect, "SELECT " . $request . " FROM users WHERE username = ?")) {

      /* bind parameters for markers */
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);

      /* bind result variables */
      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $return);

      /* fetch value */
      mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);     
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: ah, i focused on `$username` and blanked on the column.  i'll update it.

Comment: A white-list like this is a much safer way of doing it. Good answer.